# How to sum a count query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to sum 3 different values after i use the count.
This is the query i'v got to get 3 different values.

```
SELECT f.filmid, filmtitel, count(award_type)
FROM film F
INNER JOIN film_award_uitreiking FAU ON F.filmid = FAU.filmid
INNER JOIN Film_award FA ON FA.awardid = FAU.awardid
WHERE fau.filmid = 4317
GROUP BY FA.award_type
ORDER BY count(fau.awardid) DESC;
```

Now i want to sum them together any suggestions ?

Comment: What does "sum them together" mean here, and can you add some sample data?

Comment: `.. GROUP BY FA.award_type WITH ROLLUP ..`. And `GROUPING()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(atcount) from
(
SELECT f.filmid, filmtitel, count(award_type) as atcount
FROM film F
INNER JOIN film_award_uitreiking FAU ON F.filmid = FAU.filmid
INNER JOIN Film_award FA ON FA.awardid = FAU.awardid
WHERE fau.filmid = 4317
GROUP BY FA.award_type
) x
```